# How to make Symfony2 set the MySQL time_zone?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, timezone

How can I set custom driver options in Symfony2?

In this case I want to run `SET time_zone = '-04:30'` in MySQL as part of the connection initialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set in `app/config/config.yml` the following:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # Here we configure the custom driver options
        # In this case is PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND
        # The constant can not be used in this context
        options: {1002: "SET time_zone = '-04:30'"}
```

Comment: First of all, if possible, try to use UTC for date/time storage (in other words, you won't need this). But if needed (ie, a legacy system), after the timezones have been loaded into MySQL's table (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) you can use a named timezone, such as "America/Edmonton" instead of the offset. This means you won't have to adjust this for daylight saving or other time changes (as long as MySQL's timezone data is correct).

Answer (score -1):

Unlike `Symfony 1.4`, there isn't a `default_timezone` config parameter to set the default timezone in Symfony2. I’m not sure about the reasons for this, but if you like keeping as much of your configuration within the app, then use the code below.
Set the default timezone (and any similar PHP configuration) by overriding the `AppKernel#init()` function. Remember to call its parent.

```
<?php
// AppKernel.php

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    //..
    //.......
    //...........
    // --- Append the init function below ---

    public function init()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Kolkata' );
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Or you can edit `php.ini`

```
datetime = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

**Note:** init method was [deprecated](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/commit/9141877ff6d64a422e249510a84940be3ff6f35f#diff-1) since version 2.3, to be removed in 3.0. You must move your logic in the constructor instead:

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}
```

Comment: Deonia, this does not work in `symfony2`, at least I couldn't find any docs about it.

Comment: @Cesar I mistakenly gave you v1.4 method before. Try above edited answer

Comment: I hope the title in my question is clear enough, I needed it to set the time zone of the mysql server, not the timezone of php, any way the answer that I wrote is correct, I answered my own question because stackoverflow promotes answering own questions, any way your answer help me too, beacuse now I know how to set php timezone in symfony2, so the two timezones  are synchronized. Thanks!